# Angular 7 min length validation error not showing reactive forms

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-forms

Form validation min length validation error not showing i am using reactive forms

```
<div [formGroup]="subMerchant">
    <ion-item class="inputDesign">
            <ion-input placeholder="Enter Sub Merchant Mobile no" formControlName="SubMercMobileNo" type="tel" maxlength="10"></ion-input>
          </ion-item>
          <ion-text class="errorText" color="danger" *ngIf="subMerchant.controls.SubMercMobileNo.errors && submitted == true">
            <p [hidden]="!subMerchant.controls.SubMercMobileNo.errors.required">Mobile is required</p>
            <p [hidden]="!subMerchant.controls.SubMercMobileNo.errors.minlength">Enter minlength 10</p>
            <p [hidden]="!subMerchant.controls.SubMercMobileNo.errors.pattern">Enter valid is Mobile No</p>
          </ion-text>
</div>

  subMerchant: FormGroup;
 this.subMerchant = this.formBuilder.group({
      SubMercMobileNo: ['', Validators.compose([
        Validators.required,
        Validators.minLength(10),
        Validators.pattern("[0-9]{0-10}")
      ])],
 );
```

Comment: Can I see your component code? What did you write when you initialise your formgroup/formbuilder?

Comment: did you pass the `Validators.maxLength` to formcontrol

Comment: @sanchila i need min length and max length 10

Comment: `[hidden]="!subMerchant.controls.SubMercMobileNo.hasError('minlength')` In your HTML try this.

Answer (score 4):

```
<div [formGroup]="subMerchant">
<ion-item class="inputDesign">
        <ion-input placeholder="Enter Sub Merchant Mobile no" formControlName="SubMercMobileNo" type="tel" minlength="10"></ion-input>
      </ion-item>
      <ion-text class="errorText" color="danger" *ngIf="subMerchant.controls.SubMercMobileNo.errors && submitted == true">
        <p [hidden]="!subMerchant.controls.SubMercMobileNo.errors.required">Mobile is required</p>
        <p [hidden]="!subMerchant.controls.SubMercMobileNo.errors.minlength">Enter minlength 10</p>
        <p [hidden]="!subMerchant.controls.SubMercMobileNo.errors.pattern">Enter valid is Mobile No</p>
      </ion-text>
```

Comment: Why are you using  [hidden]="!..", you can use 'ngIf'

Answer (score 0):

You have not used minlength="a number" on  element

Comment: tried minlength="a number" on element its not working also in input allow only 10 numbers to enter

Comment: it restricts to 10 number because of maxlength="10". You should replace "a number" with real number like 3.